# SwiftUI - NavigationBar in View from NavigationLink quickly showing then disappearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swiftui

I have a `ContentView` containing a `NavigationView` that leads to a `DestinationView`. I want to hide the navigation bar in the `ContentView`, but show it in the `DestinationView`. To hide it in the `ContentView` I set `navigationBarHidden` to `true` and give `navigationBarTitle` an empty string. 
In the `DestinationView` I set `navigationBarHidden` to false and give it the title "DestinationView".

If I run the project and tap on the `NavigationLink`, the `DestinationView` shows the `NavigationBar` but quickly hides it after the view appeared. Can anybody help me with this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.green.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        Text("Tap me")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This bug in still present in Xcode 11.4b2. Please submit feedback to Apple.

Comment: I reported this on 2019-12-02 as FB7475351 with no feedback yet received.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use variable to achieve this and bind it with your destination

```
struct ContentView: View {
         @State var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool = true
        var body: some View {
            NavigationView {

                ZStack {
                    Color.red.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(isNavigationBarHidden: self.$isNavigationBarHidden)) {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.green.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            Text("Tap me")
                        }
                    }

                }
                .navigationBarHidden(self.isNavigationBarHidden)
                .navigationBarTitle("")
                .onAppear {
                    self.isNavigationBarHidden = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct DestinationView: View {
        @Binding var isNavigationBarHidden: Bool
        var body: some View {
            List {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")

            .onAppear {
                self.isNavigationBarHidden = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is great! You can omit the `.navigationBarHidden(false)` though since the parent view will do this when the binding changes.

Comment: Great answer :) Learned something new aswell

Comment: @jawadAliThank you I spent a long time trying to figure this out and don't think I would have if it weren't for your post, thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Jawad You sir, just saved my day

Comment: The drawback of this solution is it can not deal with a case with dynamically creating a destination. I think @Norman solution below is better

Answer (score 1):

Edit: use the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60526662/86093) as it's a *much* cleaner solution.

---

I encountered this bug and ended up using `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to wrap a controller which sets the navigation bar hidden state in its `viewDidAppear` method:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.green.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        Text("Tap me")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
        .background(HorribleHack())
    }
}

struct HorribleHack: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> HorribleHackViewController {
        HorribleHackViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: HorribleHackViewController, context: Context) {
    }
}

class HorribleHackViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually works. Using this method, allows us to show/hide the navigation bar dynamically upon user actions.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the safe area layout guide

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                VStack {
                    NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()) {
                        ZStack {
                            Color.green.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            Text("Tap me")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("1")
                Text("2")
            }
        }.navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

Happy Coding...

Answer (score 1):

For me passing a binding around through the view hierarchy wasn't optimal, adding the state to an environment var was preferable.

```swift
class SceneState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isNavigationBarHidden = true
}


class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
...
    var sceneState = SceneState()

...
    let contentView = ContentView().environmentObject(sceneState)
...
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            View1()
        }
    }
}

struct View1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneState: SceneState
    @State private var showView2: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("NO nav bar.")
            Button("Go to View2") {
                self.showView2 = true
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: View2(), isActive: $showView2, label: {EmptyView()})
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(self.sceneState.isNavigationBarHidden)
        .navigationBarTitle("")
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(self.sceneState.isNavigationBarHidden)
    }
}


struct View2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var sceneState: SceneState

     var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("WITH nav bar.")
        }
            .navigationBarHidden(self.sceneState.isNavigationBarHidden)
            .navigationBarTitle("WWDC")
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(self.sceneState.isNavigationBarHidden)
            .onAppear {
                self.sceneState.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I use this approach and I believe this is the best one!

Answer (score 0):

There ist actually a really simple solution to this problem. After many tries I figured it, that you have to add the `.navigationBarHidden(false)` directly to the destination view inside the `NavigationLink` like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                Color.red.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView()
                   .navigationBarHidden(false)) {
                    ZStack {
                        Color.green.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        Text("Tap me")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("")
            .navigationBarHidden(true)
        }
    }
}

struct DestinationView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Text("1")
            Text("2")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("DestinationView")
        .navigationBarHidden(false)
    }
}
```

It will work like desired, and won't disappear after showing up.

Answer (score 0):

I run this code on an iOS 14 Simulator and the navigation bar did not hide, so I assume this might be an issue with iOS 13. I had a similar problem and my code which resulted in nav bar disappearing on iOS 13.5 Simulator worked fine on iOS 14.4 Simulator.